# How to find divisor of a number that is closest to its square root?

Tags: java

I've been trying to make a program that gives me a divisor of a number `n` that is closest to its square root.

I've tried to accomplish this by using this program:

```java
public static int closestDivisor(int n) {
    for (int i = n/ 2; i >= 2; i--) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However, when I run this:

```java
System.out.println(closestDivisor(42));
```

I get `21` when expecting either `6` or `7` because those are the closest divisors of 42.

Comment: Program is doing everything right...Go Machines!!!!

Comment: 21 is a divisor of 42, since 42 / 21 = 2.

Comment: You need to change the definition of the function accordingly. Indeed 21 is closer to 42 than 6 or 7.

Comment: Why do you expect a function that returns a single `int` to return two? Maybe you need to define "closest divisors".

Comment: Perhaps you mean, the divisor closest to the square root? If so, you need a little bit of extra logic to remember the most recently found divisior where n / i < i, and then return that when you find a divisor with n / i > i (and of course just return i if n / i == i)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, maybe I need to define it a little bit more: By `closest divisors` (and I think that should be obvious by looking at my expected answers) I mean two numbers (like 6 and 7) that are closest to each other. The number 42 has these divisors: `1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42`. In these divisors, the numbers `6` and `7` are closest to each other. If I got `6` as a return value, I could easily calculate the `7`.

Comment: @DerEchtePilz so are 1 and 2, and 2 and 3, so why not them?

Comment: I am feeling more and more sure what we want are the divisors closest to the square root. For 42, 6 and 7 are those.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think what the OP meant was closest divisors to each other. 6 and 7 are closest because 6*7 = 42. On the other hand, 1 and 2 are not, because 1*2 != 42. And 2 and 21 are not because they're not as close to each other as 6 and 7.

Comment: @k314159 yes, that was already clarified by an edit after my comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (i < 4) return 1;

int divisor = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (i * i == n) return i;
    if (i * i < n && n % i == 0) divisor = i;
    if (i * i > n) return divisor;
}

return -1; // never executed, unreachable
```

This code should return the largest number which evenly divides n and which is less than or equal to the square root of n.

You can then look at this number, let's call it answer, and n/answer, and one of those is guaranteed to be the factor of n closest to the square root of n. To see which is which, we can compare n - answer*answer and (n/answer * n/answer) - n, and see which is smaller; if the first difference is smaller then answer is closer to n, otherwise n/answer is closer to n.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

- First, return `-1` if the candidate is `< 0 or 1 if < 4`
- If `n` is a perfect square, return the square root.

Now inside the loop, Start from the `square root` and work outwards checking both sides of the square root for divisibility.

- The default divisor is initialized to `-1`.
- As the condition is evaluated either `i` divides `n` and `i` is returned via `divisor`
- Otherwise `k` divides `n` and `k` is returned via `divisor`.

```
public static int closestDivisor(int n) {
    if (n < 4) {
        return n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }
    int v = (int)Math.sqrt(n);
    int divisor = v;
    
    if (v * v == n) {
        return v;
    }
    for (int i = (int) v, k = i; i >= 1; i--, k++) {
        if ( n % (divisor = i) == 0
                || (n % (divisor = k) == 0)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return divisor;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int closestDivisor(int n) {
int closest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int closestDivisor = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        if (Math.abs(i - n/i) < closest) {
            closest = Math.abs(i - n/i);
            closestDivisor = i;
        }
    }
}
return closestDivisor;
```

Comment: This throws an `ArithmeticException` with every number bigger than 1. Also, what is this supposed to solve? The code in the question already works given the (original, unclear at that time) definition of the problem.

Comment: Seems like for any n other than 1, it sets divisor = n, then temp = n % divisor = 0, n = divisor = n, divisor = temp = 0, divisor < 1, n != 1, and it tries to return n/divisor = n/0 and throws an exception...